# Although using typedef of an data type before define it, no error from compiler

Tags: c, typedef

I would like to know in pre-compile phase when the compiler go to line 1. What did it do to MyType in "#define MY_RES (MyType)0x18U". The thing after that is not important.
I think compiler treat "MyType" as a string.
But I wonder why there is no warning or error.

```
1. #define MY_RES      (MyType)0x18U
2. typedef unsigned char MyType;
```

Comment: Are you using MY_RES somewhere in the code ?

Comment: @Binh Duc What error are you expecting? There is no string in the presented code snippet.

Comment: Why would it treat it as a string? There are no strings anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: `#define` creates a macro but it has no effect until it is actually used. You have not shown any uses of the `MY_RES` define.

Comment: @Dabo sure, I defined MY_RES in a header file and used it in source file.

Comment: If you used it then show us the code that uses it. What you have shown doesn't use it.

Comment: @kaylum the use of this macro is not the point here. The thing I would like to ask is the role of MyType used in the macro definition before I "typedef" it.

Comment: @kaylum for an example I just want to know in pre-compile phase. when the compiler go to this line of code. what did it do to MyType in "#define MY_RES      (MyType)0x18U".
The thing after that is not important.

Comment: That's what we are trying to tell you. Macros are not evaluated at the the point they are defined. Only when they are used.

Comment: @BinhDuc: They are two steps to consider : the preprocessing and the compilation. At preprocessing time, all the macros are substituted by their content. For example here, any occurrence of "MY_RES" will be replaced by "(MyType)0x18U". Then the compilation will generate the machine code doing all the checks. So, that' why you don't get any error from the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Macro will be removed during the preprocessing and its occurrence replaced textually.

So the compiler will compile in your case:

```
typedef unsigned char MyType;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qxxso1

you need to use it before definition to get an error

```
#define MY_RES      (MyType)0x18U
unsigned char x = MY_RES;
typedef unsigned char MyType;
```

which will be preprocessed to:

```
unsigned char x = (MyType)0x18U;
typedef unsigned char MyType;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/WGh4aE

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in the code you have reported. Define creates a macro in your code (https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/constants/create_define.php).

When you reference the macro, the preprocessor replaces the Macro name (identifier) with the replacement

#define identifier replacement

In your case, the macro is never referenced and the preprocessor just ignores it.

From a syntax standpoint, there are also no errors at all.

Please have a look to this topic
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/

Answer (score 0):

> What did it do to MyType in "#define MY_RES (MyType)0x18U"

Defines the preprocessing token `MyType` to be replaced by the replacement list of preprocessing tokens `(MyType)0x18U`.

> I think compiler treat "MyType" as a string.

Yes, preprocessor treats `(MyType)0x18U` kind-of like a string. Preprocessor is not type aware, let's say in a simplified view it's a string replacement tool. The string/token `MY_RES` will be replaced by a string `(MyType)0x18U` later in the code.

> why there is no warning or error.

Because the code you showed has no erroneous constructs.

Answer (score 0):

To answer to your question I would like to use an example.

```
    |1       #define MY_RES (MyType)0x18U                                                    
    │2       typedef unsigned char MyType;                                                   
    │3                                                                                        
    │4       int main() {                                                                    
B+> │5               char c = MY_RES;                                                        
    │6               return 0;                                                               
    │7       }
```

Now if I disassemble main function:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
    0x00005555555545fa <+0>:     push   %rbp
    0x00005555555545fb <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
=>  0x00005555555545fe <+4>:     movb   $0x18,-0x1(%rbp)
    0x0000555555554602 <+8>:     mov    $0x0,%eax
    0x0000555555554607 <+13>:    pop    %rbp
    0x0000555555554608 <+14>:    retq
End of assembler dump.
```

You can just ignore all of line and take a look at line#3(marked with arrow sign). As you can see, it it just moving an immediate data(0x18) to -0x1(%rbp), which is char c in our case. So, what I am trying to say is that the compiler would have done something like:

```
char c = MY_RES
char c = (MyType)0x18U
char c = (char)0x18U    //since MyType is just an alias name for char
```

Answer (score 0):

A `#define` directive defines a macro to be substituted later.

The contents of a macro replacement are not analyzed until the macro is encountered in later source text and is replaced. So the fact that a name in the macro is not defined before the macro is defined is not a problem. The compiler analyzes the name only after the macro is replaced, not when the macro is defined.